# Interpreting Sentry frequency graph

Tags: python, sentry

Sentry provides nice graphs to show message frequency, but little information about what do they actually show.

[image]

Are these messages per minute? 5 minutes? 15 minute? hour?

Comment: It would be interesting to know why is this important.

Comment: It's a direct measure of how severe problem is. Without knowing that you cannot calculate for example if problem occurs for example in 1% of request or 0.1% of requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This chart are by minute. This is the model reponsible to store the data for that graph.

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/blob/15c0291074087408c6f66ac1619365b148b9084c/src/sentry/models/groupcountbyminute.py

To give you a more detailed explanation:

The main chart has a DOM attribute `data-api-url` that points to `sentry-api-chart` view that returns the data from `Project` model from a `ProjectManager` mixed with this class:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/blob/15c0291074087408c6f66ac1619365b148b9084c/src/sentry/manager.py#L117

That class fetch the related time span from the previous model and returns the data.